# Rect Js router stop when routes import from external file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

i working by react js router (react-router-dom v4.2) and **Redux** together and have strange varios problem

first i say i successfully used and run this but the problems

1. when i use the root route as first rote in route list router stop working!!

but when i use '/' route as last route everything is ok

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
  <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
  <Route path="/" component={Home} axact />
</Switch>
```

2. when i create routes as external component and import it to app routes not work

this is my route.js codes

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
// import Components
import Home from './components/Home'
import Blog from './components/blog/Blog'
import Users from './components/users/Users'

class router extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Home} axact />
                    <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
                    <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default router;
```

this is my  App.js codes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getUsers } from './store/actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Nav from './components/navigation/Nav';
import axios from 'axios';

const userApi = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

class App extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get(userApi)
            .then(response => {
                let users = response.data
                this.props.getUserList(users)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Nav />
                <Router />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ getUserList: (api) => dispatch(getUsers(api)) })

export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

when i use this codes everything is ok

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getUsers } from './store/actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from './components/Home'
import Blog from './components/blog/Blog'
import Users from './components/users/Users'
import Nav from './components/navigation/Nav';

import axios from 'axios';

const userApi = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(userApi)
      .then(response => {
        let users = response.data
        this.props.getUserList(users)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Nav />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
          <Route path="/users/" component={Users} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} axact />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ getUserList: (api) => dispatch(getUsers(api)) })

export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

Comment: What is <Route path="/" component={Home} axact /> axact ? correct it ..it is exact which is irrelevant with switch. Remove it

Comment: GOD!!!!
i cant believe it....
your right...
all of the problems thats it!!!!
thanks man...
i still cant believe it .... aaaaahhhhh!!!!